# roscpp service calls - multithreading

Tags: ros, roscpp, service, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a service created in C++ that only handles one request at a time. Normally this would not be a problem, but my service is computing a Descartes trajectory, which takes somewhere between 3-8 seconds. Is there a way to thread the service requests such that they are taking place at the same time instead of one after the other?

Here is the current implementation of my service.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Initialize node
  ros::init(argc, argv, "compute_descartes_traj_server");
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle;  

  // Create subscriber to /joint_states topic
  Listener listener;
  ros::Subscriber sub = node_handle.subscribe("joint_states", 10, &Listener::jointStatesCallback, &listener);

  // Create ComputeDescartesTraj service
  ros::ServiceServer service = node_handle.advertiseService("compute_descartes_traj", &Listener::ComputeDescartesTraj, &listener);
  ROS_INFO("-----------------------------------------------");
  ROS_INFO("Ready to compute Descartes trajectory.");  
  ROS_INFO("-----------------------------------------------");

  // Keep ROS service running until it is shutdown
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
 }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258931/roscpp-service-calls---multithreading/) by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 592 on 2017-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems this question is about multithreading in ROS. There are a few ways to do this. You can take a look at:  http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning

Below is a minimal example with AsyncSpinner:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   ros::init(argc, argv, "your_node");

   //Any init here

   ros::Rate loop_rate(10.0); //Choose the loop rate
   ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(10); //Choose how many threads
   spinner.start();

   while (ros::ok()) {
     //Do any periodical work here
     ros::spinOnce();
     loop_rate.sleep();
   }

   ros::waitForShutdown();

   return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) with karma: 544 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-11**:
This will work, but make sure that your service handlers are either idempotent or use proper locking of resources if you run them in parallel.